# we are not able to see any metrics being collected by google analytics. No errors but no metrics is being collected

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-analytics

We are trying to track users and their behavior who visit our app using google analytics plugin.We have built our app on Cordova, however, the analytics plugin seem to not work with cordova framework. If anyone can help with solving this, that would be great. The following is the code we have used for integration:

```
onDeviceReady() 
{ 
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        if (typeof window.analytics !== undefined){
           window.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-12090XXX-X'); 
        } else {
           console.log("error in analytics");
        }
    },3000);
}
```

Versions

Ionic v1

Cordova version 6.1.2

cordova-plugin-google-analytics spec="~1.8.3"

Comment: What do you mean by "seem to not work"? What did you expect and what did actually happen?

Comment: we are not able to see any metrics being collected by google analytics. No errors but no metrics is being collected

Comment: Ok. You should add this clarification to the question.